# The form of Lagrangian for a free particle

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, inertial-frames

I've just registred here, and I'm very glad that finally I have found such a place for questions.

I have small question about Classical Mechanics, Lagrangian of a free particle. I just read [Deriving the Lagrangian for a free particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23098/8496) blog. 
So, if I am correct, we have, that the free particle moves with a constant velocity in inertial frame and also that

$$ \vec{0}~=~\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{v}}
~=~\frac{d }{dt} \left(2\vec{v}~\ell^{\prime}\right)
$$

$\ell^{\prime} $ means $\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}$ .Hence
$$ \vec{c}~=~\left(2\vec{v}~\ell^{\prime}\right)
$$

So, this two statements mean that $\ell^{\prime}$ is constant, so 
$$L~=~ \ell(v^2)~=~\alpha v^2+\beta, $$

Isn't this enough to derive the lagrangian of a free particle. If yes (but I'm sure no) why did Landau use the Galilean transformation formulas etc to derive that formula.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *No, OP's argument(v1) is not enough to derive the Lagrangian for a non-relativistic free particle.* It is true that the constant of motion mentioned by OP

$$\vec{c}~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{v}}~=~2\vec{v}~\ell^{\prime}$$

does not depend on time $t$. (It is in fact the canonical/conjugate momentum, which in general is different from the mechanical/kinetic momentum $m\vec{v}$.) However, $\vec{c}$ could still depend on e.g. the initial velocity of the particle (which is also the velocity $\vec{v}$, since we know that the velocity is constant for a free particle, cf. e.g. the first part of the linked [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/23123/2451)).

This is perhaps best illustrated by taking a simple example, say

$$L~=~\ell(v^2)~=~ v^4.$$

Then

$$\vec{c}~=~2\vec{v}~\ell^{\prime} ~=~4\vec{v}~v^2,$$

which is a constant of motion, as it should be.

Comment: Right, other functions of $v^2$ can do it, too. After all, the relativistic Lagrangian proportional to $-mc^2\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ is an example of that. For small $v$, it may be expanded as $mv^2$ plus corrections proportional to any other even power of $v$.

Comment: OK, now I really understood what was the problem!
Thank you very much!