# How to derive kinetic energy from the Lagrange equations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism

I'm having trouble deriving the kinetic energy from the Lagrange equations.  For reference, I'm following Landau and Lifshitz book, "Mechanics," which can be found for free at [Archive](https://archive.org/details/Mechanics_541).  In any case, I'm comfortable with the principle of minimal action, which leads to the Lagrange equations:

$$
L^\prime_{q}(q,\dot{q},t)-\frac{d}{dt} L^\prime_{\dot{q}}(q,\dot{q},t)=0
$$

Simply, they are the first-order optimality conditions to the optimization problem $\min\limits_q \int\limits_a^b L(q,\dot{q},t) dt$.  Next, by assuming time and space are homogenous, I can see how $L$ must be independent of both $t$ and $q$ and only be a function of $\dot{q}$.  This leads to

$$
\frac{d}{dt} L^\prime_{\dot{q}}(q,\dot{q},t)=0.
$$

Finally, by assuming space is isotropic, I can see how $L$ can not be a function of the direction of $\dot{q}$.  This is all covered on page 5 of Landau and Lifshitz book that I referred to above.  However, after this, they argue that $L$ must therefore be a function of $\dot{q}^2$.  This is where I'm confused and have the following questions:

1. Why does isotropy imply that L must be a function of $\dot{q}^2$?
2. Why doesn't isotropy instead imply that $L$ must be a function of a scalar quantity of $\dot{q}$?  A quantity like $\cos(\dot{q}^2)$ doesn't depend on direction either.
3. If isotropy does indeed imply that $L$ is a function of the magnitude of $\dot{q}$, then why do we use, essentially, $\|\dot{q}\|^2$?  Isn't the actual magnitude of $\dot{q}$ the quantity $\|\dot{q}\|=\sqrt{\dot{q}^2}$?

Anyway, the rest of the derivation of kinetic energy sits on page 7 of the above book.  Their discussion really lies on the idea that $L$ must be a function of $\dot{q}^2$, which is what I'm trying to clarify above.

---

### Edit 1

Alright, so it looks like this question has been asked in [various](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/why-does-lagrangian-of-free-particle-depend-on-the-square-of-the-velocity) [forms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93902/landaus-argument-for-dependence-of-lagrangian-on-magnitude-of-velocity), so before it closed out it'd help me if I could clarify some points in those answers that apply to here.  Yes, the short answer is that the Lagrangian needs to be invariant to the Galilean transform.

From what I can see, the Lagrangian is invariant to scalar multiplication and functions of the form $\frac{d}{dt} f(q,t)$.  This last one is due to

$$
\arg\min\limits_q \int\limits_a^b L(q,\dot{q},t) + \frac{d}{dt} f(q,t)dt
$$
$$
=\arg\min\limits_q \int\limits_a^b L(q,\dot{q},t)dt+f(q^{(b)},t_b)-f(q^{(a)},t_a)
$$
$$
=\arg\min\limits_q \int\limits_a^b L(q,\dot{q},t) dt
$$

since constants don't change the location of the minima.  This is discussed around equation (2.8) in Landau.  Anyway, if the Lagrangian is a scalar function in terms of $\dot{q}$, then we have that $L(q,\dot{q},t)=\phi(\dot{q})$ for some $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  Further, Galilean invariance states that the Lagrangian should be invariant to transformation $\hat{q} = q + Vt$ or $\dot{\hat{q}} = \dot{q} + V$.  Combining all of this, we have that

$$
\phi(\dot{\hat{q}}) = \phi(\dot{q}+V) = \phi(\dot{q}) + \phi^\prime(\dot{q})V + o(\|V\|)
$$
Hence, we need that $\phi^\prime(\dot{q})V = \frac{d}{dt} f(q,t)$ for some $\phi$ and some $f$ in order for the Lagrangian to be invariant to the Galilean transformation.  Certainly, $\phi(\dot{q})=\dot{q}^2$ and $f(q,t) = 2\langle q,V\rangle$ does this. How do we guarantee that this is the only solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Lagrangian of free particle depend on the square of the velocity ?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63370/)

Comment: Better change the title of your question so that it may highlight what your latest query is and also clarify how it is different from the dupe ones.

Comment: The edited question (v3) is essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23098/2451