Proving that the Lagrangian of a free particle depends only on $|\boldsymbol{v}|^2$

The question is NOT answered by
Deriving the Lagrangian for a free particle,
as the answers therein assume the quadratic dependence, which is what
I am trying to prove. Additionally,  while one of the deeply linked
answers does attempt to argue that the Lagrangian should depend on the
square of the velocity, the argument is difficult / impossible for me to follow, to the extent that
my goal is to make a simpler and clearer one, with all the assumptions and steps made very explicit.

I'm going through Landau and Lifshitz's Mechanics, in particular, their derivation of the Lagrangian of a free particle, and an elaboration of their approach in Lawrie's A Unified Grand Tour of Theoretical Physics (3.1, The Action Principle in Galilean Spacetime).
I am having trouble fleshing out a proof that the Lagrangian of a free particle depends only on the magnitude of the velocity $|\boldsymbol v|$, having shown that it cannot depend explicitly on the position nor the time.
The texts do not elaborate on this point, but based on my review of other similar questions, I believe we can proceed as follows. Assuming that $\mathcal L = \mathcal L(\boldsymbol {v})$ is a function of the velocity only, the isotropy of space is implemented as a symmetry of the Lagrangian under the infinitesimal rotation $\boldsymbol v \longrightarrow \boldsymbol v + (\delta\theta)\,\boldsymbol{\hat {n}}\times\boldsymbol v $. Expanding the Lagrangian to first order:
$$
\mathcal {L}(\boldsymbol v + (\delta\theta)\,\boldsymbol{\hat {n}}\times\boldsymbol v )
\approx \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol v) + \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v}\cdot \left((\delta\theta)\,\boldsymbol{\hat {n}}\times\boldsymbol v \right)
$$
If the Lagrangian doesn't change, then $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v}\cdot \left(\boldsymbol{\hat {n}}\times\boldsymbol v \right) = 0$. Using properties of the triple product,
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v}\cdot \left(\boldsymbol{\hat {n}}\times\boldsymbol v\right)  = \boldsymbol{\hat {n}}\cdot \left(\boldsymbol v \times \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v}\right)  = 0
$$
If this is true for all rotations, then $\boldsymbol v \times \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v}= \boldsymbol 0$. In general, this requires that $ \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v}$ is parallel to $\boldsymbol v$ (I think?), hence
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \boldsymbol v} = f(\boldsymbol v)\,\boldsymbol v
$$
where $f(\boldsymbol v)$ is some unknown scalar function.
The problem: I don't know how to finish this argument and conclude that $\mathcal {L} $ is a function of the magnitude of velocity alone. I am looking for as rigorous an argument as possible - if we need to make additional assumptions to conclude $\mathcal L = \mathcal L(|\boldsymbol {v}|^2)$, that's fine, but I would like to make them explicit.
I noticed that taking one of the components of the above relation, and rearranging things a bit gives:
$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial v_i}\frac{1}{ f(\boldsymbol v = (v_1, v_2, v_3))}=v_1
$$
The RHS doesn't depend on $v_2$ or $v_3$, so the LHS should also not depend on them. However, I am not sure if this is helpful. I also know we can't just conclude $f$ should be a constant, as this immediately yields $\mathcal {L} = \text{const} \times \,v^2$ - something which the two texts derive using an additional argument, implementing symmetry under an infinitesimal Galilean boost.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23098/2451 and links therein.

@Qmechanic, respectfully, I have seen these answers before, and I don't think my question is really a duplicate . In fact, I found your elaboration of the argument that $\boldsymbol v=  const$ (alongside exploring the other branch) very informative, it helped me get comfortable with that part of the argument!
I also saw your argument about isotropy, but a) unfortunately, I find it difficult to follow and b) it appears to be different approach from one in my question (you require the $\Delta L$ to be a total time derivative. Can't we use the same approach as for position and time?).

You have to follow the argument very closely if you don't want to drop into a dead end. Your question is really answered by Qmechanic's answer.

Respectfully, once again: it's not a duplicate of the directly linked question as the answers take quadratic dependence on velocity as a starting point. It could be a duplicate of some of the questions in the rabbit hole of the links therein.
I find the argument in QMechanic's answer difficult to follow, so I attempted to make a similar argument, starting from scratch (but based on similar arguments I found, this QMechanics' one included). I was hoping it could be fleshed out.
If somehow that is not enough effort, feel free to close as duplicate, sure.

@naturallyInconsistent Please read the question carefully. The OP is not asking how to prove the claim (which would indeed make it a duplicate), but rather how to finish their own argument presented here.

@VincentThacker and I am trying to convey that the argument is not so simple that it can be easily converted the way that the OP wants. It is not at all a given that the OP's argument is finish-able, and I know that because I tried making that argument myself. The OP would be far better placed if the OP is guided towards fully understanding the completed arguments that had already been presented, rather than making alternative arguments without first understanding the presented argument.

@naturallyInconsistent You're missing the point. I'm not commenting on the veracity of OP's argument in any way. It's not asking the same question so it is not a duplicate. That's it. In other words, asking how to do a problem is different from asking about the correctness/finishability of a proposed solution. And anything from "The OP would be far better placed if the OP is guided towards fully understanding the completed arguments..." is your own opinion. So the correct action is to leave a link to the other question rather than closing it as a duplicate of said question.

You cannot prove such symmetry without introducing some additional assumption about the Lagrangian that is equivalent to it. In general, Lagrangian for a particle can depend on components of velocity, e.g. Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2}m(v_x^2+v_y^2 + v_z^2) + P_xv_x + P_yv_y + P_zv_z + Q$ with constant $P_x,P_y,P_z,Q$. It has dependence on $P$'s and $Q$, but this does not in any way affect equations of motion. So we can drop those terms, but we do not have to - it has not effect. So Lagrangian can be many things, not merely $\frac{1}{2}m(v_x^2+v_y^2 + v_z^2)$.

More generally, this is a consequence of invariant theory. E.g.:

If $I=f\left(({\bf v}_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}\right)$ is invariant under $G=SO(3)$, then $I$ is a function  $I=g\left(({\bf v}_i\cdot {\bf v}_j)_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}\right)$ of the inner products.

If $I=f({\bf v})=g(|{\bf v}|,\theta,\phi)$ is invariant under $G=SO(3)$, then $I=h(|{\bf v}|)$ is a function of the magnitude $|{\bf v}|$ of the vector ${\bf v}$.


