# Why is the symmetry variation $\delta_s q$ different from the ordinary variation $\delta q$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

I was reading about *symmetry of action* when I came before the *symmetry variation* in *Particles and Quantum Fields* by *H. Kleinert*; there he wrote:

> Symmetry variations must not be confused with ordinary variations $\delta q(t)$ used to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations. While the ordinary variations
>   $\delta q(t)$ vanish at initial and final times, $\delta q(t_b) = \delta q(t_a) = 0,$ the symmetry variations $\delta_s q(t)$ are usually non-zero at the ends.

So, isn't $\delta_s q$ a *virtual* variation? For, if it would be, it should have vanished in the fixed initial and final time, $t_a$  and $t_b$, isn't it?

Could anyone explain me why the symmetry  variation is different from the ordinary variation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Kleinert calls *symmetry variations* and *ordinary variations* are used in 2 different contexts. Both are off-shell variations.

1. *Symmetry variations* should leave the action invariant up to boundary terms. (In the affirmative case, one can then apply [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) to deduce a conservation law.) They have typically a specific prescribed form with possibly both horizontal and vertical components, i.e. components in $t$- and $q$-space, respectively.
2. *Ordinary variations* are performed to find [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). They are general vertical transformations that satisfy pertinent boundary conditions. Boundary conditions must be imposed to get rid of boundary terms.