# Boundary terms and Symmetries

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, boundary-conditions, noethers-theorem, boundary-terms

Consider Maxwell-Chern-Simons theory in 2+1 dimension, with Lagrangian $$L = -(1/4)F_{\mu v}F^{\mu v} + (m^2/4) \epsilon_{\mu v \rho}A^\mu F^{v \rho},$$ when I make a gauge transformation $A_\mu \to A_\mu + d\lambda$, the lagrangian changes by a total derivative, which we can change it to surface integral. We assume the total derivative term, which can be converted to surface integral, vanishes at large distances. If we don't assume this does this change the symmetries or does it change the conserved quantities (i.e change the momentum, angular momentum operator etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what OP is actually asking, but perhaps it is worth stressing the following point:

1. On one hand, pertinent boundary conditions (BCs) are assumed to derive [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).
2. On the other hand, BCs are *not* assumed in [Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)'s two [theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem).

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299111/2451) Phys.SE post.