# Differences between the variations in Noether's theorem and Hamilton's Principle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

Noether’s theorem can be defined for the invariance of the action under
variations of paths induced by a coordinate transformation which depends continuously on a parameter, $\epsilon$, $q_i(t) \rightarrow \bar{q}_i(t, ε)$, $\bar{q}_i(t, 0) = q_i(t)$.

What differences are there between the variations, $δ_{q_i}$, considered in Hamilton’s principle, and the variations considered in Noether’s theorem?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference, since both variations can be thought of as a bunch of virtual displacements.

Comment: In Hamilton's principle, the variation of the trajectory must vanish at the initial and final point.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299111/2451