# The Conservation Laws in Peskin and Schroeder (page 309)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, path-integral, noethers-theorem

I'm working on the Conservation Laws in Peskin (page 309), but I was confused for it.

In last section, I know that

**Classical**: the action is stationary.i.e. $\delta S =0$  when  $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi(x)+\epsilon(x)$, so we obtain Euler-Lagrange equation

**Quantum:** the generating functional is invariant.i.e. $\delta Z[J]=0$ when $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi(x)+\epsilon(x)$, so we obtain Dyson-Schwinger equations

However, when I started to derive Noether's theorem, I got confused.

When $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi(x)+\epsilon(x)\Delta\phi_a(x)$ (Eq.9.93), in the classical case and in the quantum case, **which is stationary?**

What's the difference between $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi(x)+\epsilon(x)$ and $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi(x)+\epsilon(x)\Delta\phi(x)$, they're both infinitesimal transformations. **Why would one give DS equations and one give Noether theorem?**  What are the differences and connections between them？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The core of OP's question seems to be the following question:

   > What's the difference between (1) the infinitesimal variations to derive EL equations, and (2) the infinitesimal symmetry variations in Noether's theorem?

   This is explained in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299111/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. Concerning the [Schwinger-Dyson (SD) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation), they are derived using a vertical translation symmetry (which is formally of type 2) in the target space of the fields.

   Other SD-like equations can be derived using other symmetry variations (2) if they exist. This is e.g. useful to derive Ward identities.