# Clarification on Noether’s Theorem

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, boundary-conditions, noethers-theorem, boundary-terms

Consider a particle which occupy $(t_1,q_1)$ and $(t_2,q_2)$ where $t$ denotes time and $q$ denotes spatial coordinate. The dynamics of the particle is determined by extremising $$S[q]=\int^{t_2}_{t_1}L(q,\dot{q},t)dt$$
which is the well-known Hamilton’s principle in non-relativistic theories. It is stated and proved in Goldstein’s Classical Mechanics that the dynamics of the particle will not change if we change the Lagrangian $L$ by a total derivative of a function which is dependent on $q$ and $t$ **only**.
$$L\mapsto L(q,\dot{q},t)+\frac{dK(q,t)}{dt}$$
will not change the path which extremises the action. I would like to verify this statement because in one of Qmechanic’s [posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/189692/2451) he said there is no constraint on the form of $K$, i.e. you can take $K(q,\dot{q},t)$ as well and this is also what my lecture notes say. Yet I am not so sure about that because we do not fix the velocities at end points (whereas we fix $q$ at end points).

This leads to the second question concerning the derivation of energy-momentum tensor. The energy momentum tensor is defined as the conserved current arising from space-time symmetry, where the transformation on space-time is $x^\mu\mapsto x^\mu-\epsilon a^\mu$ for some constant $a^\mu$. A vital step in its derivation, much similar to the equaiton above, is by asserting the transformation of $\mathcal{L}$ due to it being a scalar: $$\mathcal{L}(x)\mapsto \mathcal{L}(x)+\epsilon a^\mu\partial_\mu\mathcal{L}(x).$$
Just like my problem with constraints on $K$, my problem here is the change in the Lagrangian density, whilst being a total derivative, is a total derivative of a function which depends not only on the field $\phi$ but also on its derivatives $\partial \phi$. Thus if we do have the constraint on $K$ this constraint shall apply to $\mathcal{L}$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On one hand, concerning existence of functional derivative/Euler-Lagrange equations: Here adequate boundary conditions are crucial in order to ensure that  infinitesimal variations of the action do not contain non-vanishing boundary terms.

   In particular, as is said in my linked answer, introducing $\dot{q}$-dependence in the $K$ function comes with a caveat: One has to ensure adequate boundary conditions!
2. On the other hand, concerning Noether's theorem: The [quasisymmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) transformations do *not* have to satisfy boundary conditions. Boundary terms are allowed.

Comment: I have looked at your previous answers carefully but there is one thing that remains unclear to me. Could you please clarify what do you mean by [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189690/detailed-conditions-for-symmetries-of-lagrangian/189692#189692) 'well-definedness' and 'existance' of functional derivatives when boundary condition is not set?

Comment: I am considering the classic action here. Indeed if the Lagrangian is to contain higher derivatives, not only must the Euler-Lagrange equation be modified, each additional derivative will demand one additional boundary condition. However not fixing this boundary condition seems only to affect if this path extremises the action or not and the reason for imposing such boundary conditions seems only to maintain the validity of the least action principle.

Comment: As the E-L equation is a differential principle, we are free to vary only a small portion of the path far far away from the boundary and drop any necessity of boundary condition fixing whilst still obtaining the equations of motion. But in doing so we only sacrificed the validity of least action principle and not the existance of functional derivative.

Comment: I updated the answer.