# Ambiguity of Lagrangian density in field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, classical-field-theory

In classical mechanics, we know $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ and $L(q,\dot{q},t)+\frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t)$ give the same Euler-Lagrange equation $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}_i}=\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial q_i}$.

What I want to know is the precise corresponding statement in (classical) field theory. Let us work in $d$ spatial dimensions and let us set $x^0=ct$.
Usually one says the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi,x)$ and $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi,x)+\partial_\mu \Lambda^\mu(\phi,x)$ give the same Euler-Lagrange equation $ \partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi,x)}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi_i}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi,x)}{\partial \phi_i}$. This is fine. (Note that $\partial_\mu\Lambda^\mu$ represents $\frac{\partial\Lambda^\mu}{\partial x_\mu}+\frac{\partial\Lambda^\mu}{\partial \phi_i}\partial_\mu\phi_i+\frac{\partial\Lambda^\mu}{\partial \partial_\nu\phi_i}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\phi_i$.)

But I also want to allow $\partial_\mu \phi_i$ dependence for $\Lambda^\mu$. For example, this situation arises when we say the term $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} F_{\mu\nu} F_{\rho\sigma}=\partial_\mu \Lambda^\mu$ with $\Lambda^\mu=2\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}A_\nu F_{\rho\sigma}$ does not change the Maxwell equation in U(1) gauge theory.

I think the condition on $\Lambda^\mu(\phi,\partial\phi,x)$ is
$$
\frac{\partial \Lambda^\mu}{\partial \partial_\nu\phi_i}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^\nu}{\partial \partial_\mu\phi_i}=0\quad...(*)
$$
for all $\mu,\nu=0,1,\cdots,d$.
This condition requires that the second term in
$$
\delta\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu\Lambda^\mu(\phi,\partial\phi,x)=\frac{\partial \Lambda^\mu}{\partial \phi_i}\partial_\mu\phi_i+\frac{\partial \Lambda^\mu}{\partial \partial_\nu\phi_i}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\phi_i+\frac{\partial \Lambda^\mu}{\partial x^\mu}.
$$
vanishes so that the Lagrangian does not contain derivatives higher than $\partial_\mu\phi_i$ (summation over repeated $i$ is assumed).

My question is: (1) is the above condition $(*)$ correct? I checked Weinberg and Peskin-Schroeder, but couldn't really find the same expression.

An answer in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87628/does-a-four-divergence-extra-term-in-a-lagrangian-density-matter-to-the-field-eq) clearly explained that even  if we do not put any condition on $\Lambda^\mu$, then the equivalent of the Euler-Lagrange equation $\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi_i}=0$ stays unchanged at least in the "bulk". However, as far as I understand this modification produces higher derivatives in the EOM.

My question is different. I want to keep the same form of Euler-Lagrange equation. I'm checking whether my condition stated above strictly keeps the EOM invariant.

---edit---

The Euler-Lagrange equation is unchanged under the condition $(*)$ because one can show
$$ \partial_\mu\frac{\partial \delta\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi_i}=\frac{\partial \delta\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_i}\quad...(**)$$
The calculation was lengthy but after all $(**)$ was true.

Comment: check this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/736152/ and links therewithin

Comment: Thanks but if I understand correctly, your question is about the Noether theorem. Here, I'm asking the change of Lagrangian without affecting the Euler-Lagrange equation. I wanted to avoid the discussion on quasi-symmetry which I am not convinced by.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322753/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321668/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Related : [Squaring the E&M (Maxwell) field strength tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481903/).

Comment: To reopen this post (v9) consider to only ask 1 focused question, preferably in the simplest situation where the pertinent issue arises.

Comment: Although I think my question is different and is not answered previously, actually I’m fine with my current understanding. Thanks!