# Proof of Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm having some trouble with some math on a problem for a physics class (looking for help with some partial derivatives, *not* an answer).

Let $$L'=L+\dfrac{dF}{dt},$$ where $L$ is a Lagrangian and $F$ is a function of $q_i$ and $t$.

Show that $L'$ satisfies the Lagrange equation.

First, I expanded: $$\dfrac{dF}{dt}=\dot{q}_i\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}.$$

Then, I took the partial of $L'$ with respect to $\dot{q}_i$ and got that $$\dfrac{\partial L'}{\partial \dot{q}_i}=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial q_i},$$ but now I have to take the full derivative of this expression with respect to time, and I don't know how to evaluate $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}.$$

I started to think that I didn't need to evaluate $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$ because it might cancel with a term from the other part of the Lagrange equation (i.e. $\dfrac{\partial L'}{\partial q_i}$), but I got that term to be $$\dfrac{\partial L'}{\partial q_i}=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}+\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial q_i^2}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}.$$  Obviously all the partials of L don't matter because, since L is a Lagrangian, all those terms will cancel out, but if someone could show me what I'm missing with this function $F$, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You made a mistake at your 4th equation and carried the error through the following equations. The 4th equation should be the total derivative of time of the partial derivative of F with respect to q, not the partial derivative with respect to time. (You can thank me by telling me where you got guidance on how to format equations like you did in your question. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451 and links therein.