# Undefined Hamiltonian for this particular Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

So, this a question from a Phd qualifying examination. Given the following Lagrangan $$L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}\text{sin}^2q,$$ what is the Hamiltonian for this system? So, finding the canonical momentum $p$ and then using $H=p\dot{q} -L$, I find that it is identically zero. Now, the answer 'Zero' was a choice in the choices of answers given but the correct answer is that the Hamiltonian is undefined. I'm not sure why this should be the answer, though this is a pretty  weird dynamical system. The Euler Lagrange equations just give an identity and the Hamiltonian equations also seem rather off. The Hamiltonian equations would are $$\dot{p}=\dot{q}=0. $$
I'm hoping someone shed some light on this, it seems that any random Lagrangian doesn't constitute a dynamical system, so what I should I be looking for?

Comment: I think it is also important to note that the fact the EL equations are always satisfied means that **any** trajectory you pick is a valid solution. In particular two systems with identical initial conditions can have radically different trajectories.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason the Hamiltonian is undefined is that converting a Lagrangian to a Hamiltonian requires:

- Finding $p$
- Writing $H=p\dot q-L$
- Expressing $H$ in terms of $p$ and $q$, eliminating all dependence on $\dot q$.

For the third step to be possible, you need to be able to define a coordinate transformation between the $(q,\dot q)$ coordinate system and the $(q,p)$ coordinate system. This requires that $(q,p)$ is a good coordinate system, in that a state of the system can be uniquely represented by a pair of $(q,p)$ coordinates. In turn, this means that the transformation $(q,\dot q)\rightarrow (q,p)$ must have nonzero Jacobian.

However, it's easy to see this is not the case. We know that $(q,p)=(q,\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 q)$. Thus, the Jacobian is

$$
J=\left|\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0\\\sin(q)\cos(q) & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right| = 0
$$

That means we CAN'T write $p$ as a function of $q,\dot q$, and there can't be a Hamiltonian $H(p,q)$ that is a function of only the coordinates $(p,q)$ because the coordinates $(p,q)$ don't specify the state of the system.

Answer (score 13):

1. OP's Lagrangian $$L~:=~\frac{\dot{q}}{2}\sin^2(q)~=~\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{q}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\sin(2q)\right)\tag{1}$$ is a total time derivative, so the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation is a triviality $0=0$,  cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/2451) Phys.SE post, and hence not suitable to determine physical trajectories. In other words, $q$ is a [gauge degree of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory). If $q$ is supposed to be a physical observable, then the Lagrangian (and Hamiltonian) formulations are ill-defined.
2. The Hamiltonian is defined as the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of the Lagrangian, and hence formally defined as
   $$ 
   \begin{align} 
   H(q,p)&:=~ \sup_{v\in\mathbb{R}}(vp-L(q,v))\cr 
   &=~ \sup_{v\in\mathbb{R}}v\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(q)\right)\cr 
   &=~ \left\{\begin{array}{l}\infty\text{  if } p~\neq~\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(q),\\ 0\text{  otherwise}. \end{array}\right. \tag{2}
   \end{align}$$
3. If we instead perform the Dirac-Bergmann analysis, we find that 
   $$p~\approx~\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(q)\tag{3}$$ 
   is a [primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) (and [first class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint)) constraint. First class constraints are a hallmark of a gauge system. The Hamiltonian becomes 
   $$H(q,p,\lambda)~=~\lambda\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(q)\right),\tag{4}$$ 
   where $\lambda$ is a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). One Hamilton's equation becomes
   $$ \dot{q}~\approx~\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~\lambda, \tag{5}$$
   so not surprisingly the Lagrange multiplier is equal to the velocity.
   The other Hamilton's equation is trivial $0=0$ once we enforce the constraint (3). The Hamiltonian Lagrangian becomes
   $$ L_H(q,\dot{q},p,\lambda)~:=~p\dot{q}-H
   ~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~p\dot{q}-\lambda\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(q)\right).\tag{6}$$
   As a check, note that the Hamiltonian Lagrangian (6) turns into OP's original Lagrangian (1) if we eliminate/integrate out $\lambda$ and $p$, thereby performing the (singular) Legendre transformation in the reversed direction.

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.

Comment: So in the words of Dirac (maybe overextending...) the Hamiltonian is zero and $p=(1/2)\sin^2(q)$ is the primary constraint.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes. I updated the answer.