# Follow-up question on "Adding a total time derivative term to the Lagrangian"

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I have a question to this proof here: [Adding a total time derivative term to the Lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/)

I was asking myself why $$\frac{\partial \dot{F}}{\partial \dot{q}} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q}.\tag{1}$$ So to add a bit of context: We consider the Lagrangian $\mathcal L^{*} = \mathcal L(q, \dot{q}, t) + \frac{dF}{dt},$ where $F(q, t)$ is only a function of $q$ and $t$.

Now, $$\frac{\partial \dot F}{\partial \dot q} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} \Leftrightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} = 0, \tag{2}$$ implying that $F(q,t)$ has to satisfy the E.L. equation.

But why should it, if it is chosen arbitrarily? I hope you know what I mean, thanks!

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): It is $\dot{F}$ rather than $F$ that satisfies EL equations (2).

Comment: $\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial t}}=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it in the following way
$$dF=dF(q,t)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}dq+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt$$
$$\frac{dF}{dt}=\dot{F}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial \dot{F}}{\partial \dot{q}}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}$$

Cheers!

---

On OP's comment from the second last to last equation.

$$\dot{F}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$
The only way for $\dot{q}$ to enter in this equation is through the first term on the right, the factor $\partial F/\partial q$ and $\partial F/\partial t $ are a function of $(q,t)$. On differentiating with respect to $\dot{q}$, We get

$$\frac{\partial \dot{F}}{\partial \dot{q}}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{q}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but it hasn't made a click yet ... Could you please elaborate a bit more on how to get from your second-last to your last equation?

Comment: @MathIsFun I added two more lines of work to explain it.