# QED Lagrangian - real or complex?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dirac-equation, action, complex-numbers

I'm confused about the use of complex numbers in the QED Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_\mu\psi.$$

Clearly, the Dirac field spinor has complex components. The $\gamma^\mu$ matrices involve imaginary numbers.

Is there some algebraic magic that means that $\mathcal{L}$ always comes out real, or is it complex? And if it's complex then how does the action $\int{\mathcal{L}d^4x}$ come out real? What about $A^\mu$ - are its values real, and if so, how does the RHS of the EOM $\partial_{\nu}F^{\nu\mu}=e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$ come out real given that the $\gamma^\mu$ matrices involve imaginary components?

Comment: As @Toffomat mentioned, try to evaluate what $\mathcal{L}^*$ comes out to be. Clearly some terms are real by construction, such as the terms involving only $A_\mu$s. The other can be found very easily.

Comment: OK I take it from these comments that the answer is "algebraic magic makes it real", which I will work my way through. Thanks.

Comment: Note that when calculating the complex conjugate, there are serveral places where there exist different conventions (sign of the metric, Hermitean/anti-Hermitean $\gamma$s etc.), so be careful

Comment: Did you work this through? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's Lagrangian density is up to a [total divergence term](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451) equal to
$${\cal L}~=~\bar{\psi}(\frac{i}{2}\gamma^{\mu}\underbrace{\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\partial}_{\!\mu}}_{=\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\partial}_{\mu}-\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\partial}_{\mu}} - m)\psi - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_\mu\psi,\tag{A}$$
which in turn is real. Here we use the conventions
$$ (\gamma^{\mu})^{\dagger}~=~ \gamma^0\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^0,\qquad  (\gamma^0)^2~=~{\bf 1}.\tag{B} $$