# Lagrangians not related via a total time derivative lead to same Noether symmetries?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem, action

Having answered my initial two questions (v1), I now consider a third possibility. Consider two Lagrangians that both lead to equivalent equations of motion. Suppose that they are not related via a total time derivative and can not be written in the form $L\neq L'+\frac d{dt}\phi$.

Do they lead to the same conserved quantities by Noether's theorem?

Comment: What is a "Noether symmetry"? Do you mean a continuous global symmetry to which you can apply Noether's first theorem? Also, how can Lagragians be "related by a gauge symmetry" - typically, the Lagrangian is *invariant* under a gauge symmetry?

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you for the links, they most definitely answer the first question so I will remove that part from my question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes that is what I mean, thank you. I will update my question accordingly. :)

Comment: For the existence of Lagrangians with the same e.o.m. which are not related by the same e.o.m. see [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131925/50583). Same e.o.m. need not imply the same symmetries of the action/Lagrangian, though, cf. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/50583) about how symmetries of action, e.o.m. and solutions of e.o.m. are interrelated,

Comment: Related to the question (v3): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Once again brilliant links! Big thank you to you both for taking the time and helping me out! :D