# Invariance of lagrangian with $\frac{d}{dt}(f(q,t))$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I know that *if* we have a lagrangian such that

$$ L'=L+\frac{d}{dt}(f(q,t))$$
then the equation of motion will be the same for $L$ or $L'$.

But I would like to know if there is a proof of the opposite, ie :

If $L$ and $L'$ describe the same motion, then $$ L'=L+\frac{d}{dt}(f(q,t))$$

I don't know how to prove it?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451 and links therein.

Comment: They proove that IF L'=L+d/dt (f) THEN the equation of motion will be the same.

I am asking if there is a proof of : IF L and L' describe same motion, THEN L'=L+d/dt f

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131925/2451

Comment: Thank you.

So there is no proof of the opposite as we also can do a dilatation of our lagrangian without changing the dynamic

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.