# Show two Lagrangians are equivalent

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I need to show that these two Lagrangians are equivalent:

\begin{align}
L(\dot{x},\dot{y},x,y)&=\dot x^2+\dot y + x^2-y ,\\
\tilde{L}(\dot x, \dot y, x, y)&=\dot x^2+\dot y -2y^3.
\end{align}

It is the case iff they differ for a total derivation like $\frac{dF}{dt}(x,y)$.

In this case, the difference is $x^2+y^3$ and I can't imagine such an $F(x,y)$ whose total derivative is the one above. How should I move?

I tried with the following $F(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{3\dot x} + \frac{y^4}{4\dot y}$, but it shouldn't have the dotted terms.

Actually, I just proved they don't give rise to the same Lagrange equations, so I can conclude they're not equivalent, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I leave it to OP and the reader to prove that OP's two Lagrangians are indeed classically inequivalent, but let me make the following general remarks:

1. Two Lagrangians $L_1$ and $L_2$ are classical equivalent iff they give the same Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations.
2. A sufficient condition is that the difference $L_2-L_1=\frac{dF}{dt}$ is a total derivative, but it should be stressed that it is *not* a necessary condition, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/131926/2451).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused with the \text{iff} in 1), because I know that if I take as Lagrangians $L$ and $\bar{L}=\alpha L$, they give rise to same Lagrange equations, but they're not equivalent...

Comment: @VoB It sounds like you mean something different than Qmechanic does when you say "equivalent." According to this answer, two Lagrangians are _defined_ to be equivalent whenever they give the same E-L equations.

Comment: Right. I say they're equivalent iff they differ for a total derivation. With this definition, two equivalent Lagrangians give rise to the same Lagrange-Equation. In my exercise, I couldn't find such a function $F$, so I checked that the don't give the same Lagrange-equations, in order to conclude the're not equivalent