# Action of free particle is invariant under Galilean transformation / Transformation of derivative

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I want to show that the action of a free particle is invariant under a Galilean transformation
$$
(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow (t+a,R\vec{x}+\vec{v}t+b)=(t^\prime, \vec{x}^\prime) \quad\text{where}\quad R\in O(3).
$$
Transforming the action yields
$$
S=\frac{m}{2}\int\mathrm{d}t\:\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2\rightarrow S^\prime=\frac{m}{2} \int\mathrm{d}t^\prime\:\ \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{x} ^\prime}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2 =\frac{m}{2} \int\mathrm{d}t\:\ \left(R \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}+\vec{v}\right)^2
$$
which can be rewritten as a total derivative
$$
S^\prime=\frac{m}{2}\int\mathrm{d}t\left[ \:\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2 +2\ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\vec{v}\cdot R\vec{x}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{v}^2t\right)\right].$$
However, I‘m not sure if this is correct since I assumed that the time derivative doesn‘t transform as it has a fixed definition.

Comment: Related: [Galilean invariance of Lagrangian for non-relativistic free point particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14875/2451)

Comment: @Qmechanic but it is more a question of how a derivative transforms under a coordinate transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transformation of the time derivative**

From the Galilean transformation you defined, i.e. $t' = t + a$, you can evaluate how the time derivative is transformed:
$$ \frac{d}{d t} =  \frac{dt'}{dt} \frac{d}{dt'} = \frac{d(t + a)}{dt} \frac{d}{dt'} = \frac{d}{dt'} \quad \,.$$

**Invariance of classical action of free particle**

The usage of the term 'invariance' here is a bit context-dependent. In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7700/definitions-and-usage-of-covariant-form-invariant-invariant?noredirect=1&lq=1), invariance is defined as a transformation behaviour of an object. An invariant action would transform as a scalar meaning that $S' = S$. In the case of Galilean transformation however (to continue your calculation)

$$ S' = \frac{m}{2} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt \, \bigg[\Big(\frac{dx}{dt}\Big)^2 + 2 \frac{d}{dt} \Big(\vec{v} \, \cdot \, R\vec{x}(t) \Big) + v^2 \bigg] \equiv \,  S \, + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt \bigg[ \frac{d}{dt} H(\vec{x}(t)) \bigg]  \, + \, C  $$

the action receives an additional integral over a total time derivative as well as a constant, ergo not invariant. But whenever we physicists talk about an action being invariant, we usually refer to the equations of motions, the *physics*, we obtain from it. Now as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162335/what-does-the-statement-the-laws-of-physics-are-invariant-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11885/invariance-of-lagrange-on-addition-of-total-time-derivative-of-a-function-of-coo), the total time derivative will, after integration, just give you another constant term $\Delta H = H(\vec{x}(t_2)) - H(\vec{x}(t_1))$ that is added to your action which will not have any influence on the physical quantities that are described by your action since $\delta S' = \delta S$.